# Performing a sub query alternatives

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for advice on how to get around the

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery".

On the Select PlateID From @Instances code, in the example below. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

```
DECLARE @Instances AS TABLE(PlateID INT);

INSERT INTO @Instances(PlateID)VALUES(11638),(11637),(11632),(11659)

DECLARE @NumberofPlates INT;
SELECT @NumberofPlates = COUNT(*) FROM @Instances;

SELECT Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK 
from dbo.M_Instance_Plate 
WHERE Instance_Plate_Deleted = 0 
group by Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK
having sum(case 
              when Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK not in (SELECT PlateID
                                                       FROM @Instances)
                 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       SUM(case 
              when Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK in (SELECT PlateID 
                                                   FROM @Instances) 
                 then 1 else 0 end) = @NumberofPlates;
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve? I mean what is the intention behind the conditional aggregates used in the `HAVING` clause of your query?

Comment: It started out and is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762714/sql-in-list-and-only-in-list

Comment: Please try to write a question that is self-contained so that the user will be able to grasp your intention without referring to other posts.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of the structure of the physical table you included in your query I mocked up some random data for this, and put together a query that seems to work?

```
DECLARE @Instances AS TABLE(PlateID INT);
INSERT INTO @Instances(PlateID) VALUES (11638),(11637),(11632),(11632);

DECLARE @M_Instance_Plate TABLE (Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK INT, Instance_Plate_Deleted INT, Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK INT);
INSERT INTO @M_Instance_Plate SELECT 11638, 0, 100;
INSERT INTO @M_Instance_Plate SELECT 11637, 0, 100;
INSERT INTO @M_Instance_Plate SELECT 11632, 0, 100;
INSERT INTO @M_Instance_Plate SELECT 11632, 0, 200;
INSERT INTO @M_Instance_Plate SELECT 11632, 1, 300;

DECLARE @NumberofPlates INT;
SELECT @NumberofPlates = COUNT(*) FROM @Instances;

WITH x AS (
    SELECT 
        Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_1, --Any missing
        SUM(CASE WHEN Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_2 --Has coverage
    FROM 
        @M_Instance_Plate ip
        LEFT JOIN @Instances i ON i.PlateID = ip.Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK
    WHERE 
        Instance_Plate_Deleted = 0
    GROUP BY 
        Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK)
SELECT
    Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK
FROM
    x
WHERE
    test_1 = 0
    AND test_2 = @NumberofPlates;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO @Instances(PlateID)VALUES(11638),(11637),(11632),(11659)

--DECLARE @NumberofPlates INT;
--SELECT @NumberofPlates = COUNT(*) FROM @Instances;

SELECT Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK 
FROM dbo.M_Instance_Plate p
WHERE Instance_Plate_Deleted = 0 
    AND NOT EXISTS (

        SELECT 1 
        FROM @Instances i
            LEFT JOIN M_Instance_Plate m ON i.PlateID = m.Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK
        WHERE m.Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK = p.Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK
            AND m.Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 1
        FROM @Instances i
            JOIN M_Instance_Plate m ON i.PlateID = m.Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK
        WHERE m.Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK = p.Instance_Plate_Room_Instance_ID_LNK
        GROUP BY i.PlateID
        HAVING COUNT(*) != 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Is equivalent expression (checks if plateId exists on your table variable and then matches with your variable `@numberofplates`)

```
HAVING @NumberofPlates = (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS cc
        FROM @Instances AS a
        WHERE a.PlateID = Instance_Plate_Plate_ID_LNK
        )
```